# Youtube iframe embed - gets automatically paused on the first seconds (3-6) of the video

Tags: android, ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I make use of YouTube `iframe` embed for both Android and iOS platforms. It was working fine until now but I noticed something strange on both platforms. YouTube video starts playing and on the first seconds of the video (3-6 most commonly) it gets paused.

Is that possibly a YouTube bug?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the player is in buffering state, you can try like change the state of the player to playing or call playvideo method in buffering state delegate so that the video plays automatically(if it got some data buffered)